# Flushing Database Deque

Tags: python, redis

I'm currently using the Deque module from qr in python to communicate with Redis

```
    myQue = Deque('TestDataset')
    myQue.push_front('Ringo Star') 
    myQue.pop_back()
```

I'm just playing about with it now, but I can't seem to find out any documentation on how to clear the dataset and wipe all of the data on it, is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BaseQueue class (base class for all qr provided data structures) has a **clear** method which will delete/empty the data structure. Please note deleting the queue or removing all items is the same operation with Redis.

```
myQue.clear()
```